# Woocommerce price custom class

Tags: wordpress, class, woocommerce

Can someone help me with default woocomerce prices to make it look like this:

```
<p class="price">
 <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>0.3600</bdi></span> 
        – 
 <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>600.0000</bdi></span>
```

How can i change this with php hooks or functions to:

```
<p class="price woo-custom-price">
 <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <bdi class="custom-price-one"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>0.3600</bdi></span> 
        – 
 <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <bdi class="custom-price-two"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>600.0000</bdi></span>
```

Thank for your time.

**This is that I want to change.**

[image: This is that I want to change.]

Comment: _"How can i change this with php hooks or functions to"_. Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show [what you have tried so far to solve your problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woocommerce has hook for this.

> woocommerce_product_price_class

More information below:

https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_hook/woocommerce_product_price_class/